# Command date execution

Tags: command-line, date, execute-command

I'm trying to execute this command `date +'%-4.4h %2.1d %H:%M'` however the output is not correct:

```
%-4.4h %2.1d 12:50
```

I believe that there is something wrong either with my ubuntu terminal or the code. Any advice, please?
ps: beginner

Comment: What are you expecting the specifiers `%-4.4h` and `%2.1d` to do, exactly?

Comment: Maybe : May 12 12:45

Comment: Please don't remove details from your question that make existing answers invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `%-4.4h` and `%2.1d` are not valid format specifiers for the GNU `date` command - in particular, precision modifiers don't make sense and are not supported. The accepted modifiers are:

> ```
>    After any flags comes an optional field width, as a decimal  number;  then  an  optional
>    modifier,  which is either E to use the locale's alternate representations if available,
>    or O to use the locale's alternate numeric symbols if available.
> ```

("decimal" here just means digits 0-9).

The format specifiers for full month name and day of month are `%B` and `%d` respectively (you can use lowercase `%b` or `%h` for abbreviated month name ex. `Sep` for `September`). So for example:

```
$ date +'%B %d %H:%M'
May 12 07:46

$ date +'%B %d %H:%M' -d 'today + 4 months'
September 12 07:48

$ date +'%b %d %H:%M' -d 'today + 4 months'
Sep 12 07:50
```

Note that field width specifiers are *minimum* widths, so for example

```
$ date +'%4B %4d %H:%M'
 May 0012 08:04
```

pads `May` to 4 characters, but

```
$ date +'%4B %4d %H:%M' -d 'today + 4 months'
September 0012 08:03
```

does not truncate `September` to `Sept`.

See `man date` for a full list of `%` specifiers.

Comment: @HANA I used `-d 'today + 4 months'` only to illustrate the difference between `%b` and `%B` (since the current month, `May`, is the same in both formats)

Comment: Why it doesn't pad September to Sept? So the answer on my question is that the code is not valid for the GNU date command? Any other option that would give me the same output as with this code, but in a valid way?

Comment: @HANA are you trying to represent your date string in a specific language?

Comment: next best thing would be to reformat your date string with `printf '%.4s %s %s\n' $(date +'%B %4d %H:%M' -d 'today + 4 months')`